# How can I view user reactions on my posts as an admin in a Telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to see members reaction in telegram channel

I am admin of telegram channel
and I have enabled users reaction to my posts.
Telegram does not show which user sent which reaction.
I am looking for a way to see it.
I want me only as admin see which user is send which reaction to my posts.
for example user @david has send

I already have this code but it is not working. If I press start and stop on bot nothing happens.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")

def get_reactions(message):
    for reaction in message.reactions:
        user = reaction.user
        print(f"User {user.username} reacted with {reaction.emoji} to my post.")

bot.polling()

while True:
    for update in bot.get_updates():
        message = update.message
        get_reactions(message)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Code is running")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues. First, the `while True` loop at the end is blocking the polling process, so the code inside the `@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])` decorator will never be reached. Second, the polling and the command handler should be in the same block.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
    import telebot
    from telebot import types
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Code is running")
    
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def get_reactions(message):
        if message.reactions:
            for reaction in message.reactions:
                user = reaction.user
                print(f"User {user.username} reacted with {reaction.emoji} to my post.")
    
    # Start polling
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

In this version, the polling is in the main part of the script, and the
`@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)`
decorator is used to handle all messages. This way, the `get_reactions` function will be called for every message, and it will check if there are any reactions.